# Check is Group is already present in an Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have the following piece of code wherein i am trying to check if a group is already present in an active directory. If not present, then go ahead & create the group. But my group check function is not working correct.

Can you please give some suggestions.

Below is the portion of the code which checks if the group is already present or not.

```
using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xyz"))
{
   var foundGrp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, obj);
   bool UserExists = (foundGrp != null);

   if (!UserExists)
   {
      //DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + obj, "group");
      group.CommitChanges();

      Console.WriteLine("AD Group " + obj + " has been created");
      Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
   }
}
```

And here is my entire code. I am just trying a couple of features. In the longer run i will modularize my code into separate functions. Thanks.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                /*Read the input XML File*/
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.Load(@"xyz.xml");
                var exportNode = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Export");

                for (int i = 0; i < exportNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    /*Node 1 reads block 1 of the XML*/
                    XmlNode dataNode = exportNode.ChildNodes[i];

                    var environmentNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("env");
                    var tech_domainNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("Tech");

                    string env = environmentNode.InnerText;
                    string tech_domain = tech_domainNode.InnerText;

                    var output_valueNode = dataNode.SelectSingleNode("Output_Value");
                    string obj = output_valueNode.InnerText;
                    Console.WriteLine("obj is " + obj);

                    if (tech_domain == "AD Group")
                    {
                        string path = "LDAP://OU=Security,OU=Groups,DC=xyz";
                        using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path))
                        {
                            DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + obj, "group");
                            group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = obj;

                            using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xyz"))
                            {
                                var foundGrp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, obj);
                                bool UserExists = (foundGrp != null);

                                if (!UserExists)
                                {
                                    //DirectoryEntry group = entry.Children.Add("CN=" + obj, "group");
                                    group.CommitChanges();

                                    Console.WriteLine("AD Group " + obj + " has been created");
                                    Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Technology Domain for " + obj + " is not an AD Group");
                        Console.WriteLine("====================================================");
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("===============================");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your group check function is working fine. I copy pasted the exact code onto my machine changing only the RJFDEV domain and set `obj` to a specific string: the code worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going a bout this in a very round-about way. Please check out the [Everything in Active Directory via C#.NET](http://macaalay.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/). There are three series of posts that describe using the .NET System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace to manage AD and perform CRUD operations on any given principals.